# Get back to a fragment from an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, fragment

I have three fragment in an Activity C. they are behaving as tabs. I have to go from a fragment to a new Activity X. Now i want to come back to fragment from Activity X.

I have override onBackPressed but don't know how to go back to fragment/not fragmentActivity from an Activity.

if i want to go back to an Activity to another activity i override on back pressed and using intent call that actvity..

i want to do some thing like this .. this code is for coming back to previous activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{

    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,ActivityYouLikeToGo.class);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

thanks in Advance..

Comment: In your on `BackPressed(...)` you need to `replace` or `reattach` your previous `Fragment`

Comment: I am having the same idea but don't know how to do it.. share some code sample please..

Comment: show **Arnab answer's below**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a TAG (A string name for the fragment basically) and then load the fragment using `findFragmentByTag().`

Google documentation for `findFragmentByTag()` is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Managing).

Or you can also `addToBackStack()` while calling the fragment from `FragmentTransaction`, doc link [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions).
from google docs:

> "By calling addToBackStack(), the replace transaction is saved to the
>   back stack so the user can reverse the transaction and bring back the
>   previous fragment by pressing the Back button."

Comment: I think addToBackStack() work to move between fragement. When coming back from one fragment to another/

Answer (score 7):

First, Override the  back press to goto the activity where the fragments are :-

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{

    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,ActivityYouLikeToGo.class);

    intent.putExtra("Check",1);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

then goto the ActivityYouLikeToGo.java file and in onCreate do this:-

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String s1 = intent.getStringExtra("Check");

if(s1.equals("1"))
  {
s1 = "";
Fragment fragment = new YOURFRAMENTNAME();
if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer if it works for you :D

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way :

```
@Override
onBackPressed(){
finish();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when you start an activity from a fragment, the fragment never got killed,
you can simply come back to your fragment by kill the current activity by finish();,
it just like when from a fragment you open an activity and on pressing back button 
you jumped to the fragment without losing data.

Answer (score 0):

> if i want to go back to an Activity to another activity i override on
>   back pressed and using intent call that actvity

Normally, if you want to go back you don't have to do something. Pressing the device's hardware Back button will take you to the previous activity with the corresponding tab already opened.

Comment: you are saying right but this will help me not to remove the activity from stack . onBackpressing from any activity will remove the activity from stack

Comment: That is right, and I bilieve it should be like this. But, if for some reasons you don't want to have this behaviour, then you could use `viewPager.setCurrentItem(tabPosition);` to open an activity with a specific tab already opened. So you could set some flag in `onBackPressed()`, check it in your activity, and if the flag is set, then display corresponding tab.

Comment: Activity X is my player . I also want to maintain its seekbar state. so in order to do this i have to find a way to come back to fragment from activity without removing it from stack..

Answer (score 0):

You can start the activity that you are navigating to using startActivityForResult() and then while coming back to the previous activity you set the result.In the activity that you are coming back to,show the fragment depending on the resultcode. You can accomplish this task by hiding all the fragments that you dont want to show. This can work even if you are going to another activity from another fragment.

Answer (score 0):

In the activity you have started from your fragment, you can do the following:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //do whatever you want here
        finish();
        return true;
    }
```

That works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

This code works in my case. I just make an Onclick method to the button . the code is below:I made onclick method clickForFriends in Button and Id is backFriendsList, And I use android.support.v4.app.Fragment class. This method should take back from new Activity to the fragment from the Activity was launched and this method should be in the Activity after the onCreate method

```
 public void clickedForFriends(View v){
    if (v.getId() == R.id.backFriendsList){
       onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqSfX.png)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  //Here "digiM" is an Actionbar Title
    if(getTitle().equals("digiM") || getSupportActionBar().getTitle().equals("digiM"))
    {
        //reload the activity if you want to open it again as your need
        Intent intent = new Intent(Your_Current_Activity.this,Your_Current_Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

If you have action bar in that fragment, then you can check action bar title on `onBackPressed()` in Activity which contains method like.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in activity.xml:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator" />
```

then in activity.kt :

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding!!.root)

        binding!!.toolBar.setNavigationOnClickListener{
            onBackPressed()
        }
}
```

and in the overided function do this:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        finish()
    }
```

this will get you back to the same previous status of the fragment

Answer (score -2):

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(tabPosition);
```

This solution did wonders for me.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!
http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/308249