# in fragment click on button move on activity get some data click on button move back control on fragment

Tags: android

in my android application A fragment have a button(choose image) than click on that button.. move from fragment to  activity to get image .. than in activity click on button move back on fragment and display selected image. i try to move back from activity to fragment but it not work

Comment: share your code of button click

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927500/get-back-to-a-fragment-from-an-activity

Comment: this link are not my answer ...

Comment: in fragment click on a button move multiselect image activity where we select the image than click on ok button move back on fragment with select image list

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use two Fragments to achieve your goal. Let`s say , You have an activity called MainActivity.class and it is own layout called main_activity.xml , Inside main_activity you have some viewgroup called lets say.

```
<RelativeLayout 
 android:id="@+id/container_for_frgments"
 android:width="match_parent"
 android:height="wrap_content">  //Some your views   </RelativeLayout>
```

In your MainActivity.class you have to create instance of Fragments lets say A and B (Fragments).I think you know how to listen to events in fragment via Activity.

```
@Override
public void onFragmentAClickButton(){
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_main_activity,fragmentB).commit();
}
```

This methods I mean below and above are in MainActivity.class.

```
@Override
public void onFragmentBClickButton(){
  FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  manager.manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_main_activity,fragmentA).commit();
}
```

If you still questions or still dont understand , I will implement all code .